# base URL problem

Tags: drupal, url, drupal-theming

in my Drupal site

http://www.revdup.co.uk

I recently changed the domain name, I had to change a few absolute URLs and everything seems to be working fine now, except the front page, and only when I am logged in, not as a guest..

for some reason all the theme images (such as those used to build blocks appearance) are using an incorrect version of the base URL eg:

revdup.co.uk/revdup/themes/drupal_pwc010_tech/images/Block-s.png

instead of:

revdup.co.uk/themes/drupal_pwc010_tech/images/Block-s.png

I have changed the base URL variable in settings.php

Why is this only happening on one page and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to explicitly clean the template cache. Go to Administrator->Themes->Selected theme->configure->Save.
This will regenerate the template cache with correct urls. Also clear the drupal cache in Admin/settings/performance.

Comment: I had actually already worked it out and couldn't answer my own question because I don't have enough reputation point?!

Thanks anyway though, it's the thought and effort that counts :)